# pgpool Setup on Database Server

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I have three servers. One is running pgpool, another two in master-slave mode streaming replication. When installing pgpool, I was suggested to install the `pgpool_regclass` on my database servers as well. There's no problem installing it in the master node, but when I tried to do the same in the slave, I got error `ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE EXTENSION in a read-only transaction`.

I think it's because the slave is a hot standby, and `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();` returns true. So I wonder am I supposed to install `pgpool_regclass` on the slave or not. It seems not, but pgpool doc says I should install it on every database pgpool is going to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. Delete the `recovery.conf` file in the slave database, and then run `pgpool_regclass`. Otherwise, the slave is in recovery mode and cannot execute write commands.

Comment: I am confused by your answer. Shouldn't slave alway be in recovery mode and only accept read-only commands? maybe you are looking at multil master solution not master/slave. In that case, wouldn't it better if you use pgpool's replication (forwarding statements) instead of postgres's streaming replication (shipptin wal files)?